# Series over a general set

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, proof-verification

**Definition**

> Let $S$ be a set. Let $f: S \to K$ be a function where $K$ is either
>   the field of the real or the complex numbers.
>
> Then, we say that the series $\sum_{s \in S}f(s)$ converges to $F$,
>   and we write $\sum_{s \in S}f(s) = F$ iff
>
> for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a finite set $T_{\epsilon}
>  \subseteq T$ such that for all finite sets $T \subseteq S$ with
>    $T_\epsilon \subseteq T$, the inequality $\left|\sum_{s \in T}f(s)
> -F\right| < \epsilon$ holds

**Theorem:**

> Prove that $\left|\sum_{s \in S}f(s)\right| \leq \sum_{s \in S}|f(s)|$, provided that $\sum_s f(s)$ exists

**My attempt**:

Write $L = | \sum f(s)|$ and $K = \sum |f(s)|$

Assume to the contrary that $L > K$, then $L-K > 0$

Now, choose a finite set $T \subseteq S$ such that $||\sum_Tf(s)|-L| < L-K$

Then, $K-L < |\sum_T f(s)|-L$ and hence $K < \sum_T |f(s)|$

But then, $\sum_T|f(s)| \leq \sup_{T \subseteq S finite}\sum_T|f(s)| = K < \sum_T|f(s)|$. This is absurd.

Is this correct?

Comment: It holds for every finite $T$.

Comment: Yes, I know. But how do I apply this? It is not that I can take a limit or something and use that inequality gets preserved...

Comment: If you feel comfortable using normal limits. You might first show that for only countably many $x\in S$ is it the case $f(s)\neq 0$. And then reindex accordingly

Comment: I think I found a proof, using the fact that for a positive function $\sum f(s)$ is the supremum over all finite sums with indices in $S$. Could you maybe look at it?

Comment: Sure would be helpful if you had a sum over $T$ on the LHS of what you want to prove.  What happens if you split $S$ into $T$ and $S \smallsetminus T$?  (I haven't thought about it.  This is just the first thing to come to mind.  May not help.)

Comment: I think I just found a proof, but I'm unsure about it. It uses contradiction.

Comment: Sure. Let's have a look.

Comment: You don't need contradiction. Only that both limits are either bounded by or equal to sups over the finite index sets, and that for every finite index, that same index set can be used to produce an element of the other set which bounds the first.

Comment: I can't use that the $L$ is a supremum, since what is in the absolute value is not necessarily a positive function. Nevertheless, is the proof correct?

Comment: Yes, your proof is fine.